# What happened to my negative reputation?

Tags: support, reputation

Two years ago, I asked a very stupid question which got downvoted a lot, reducing my reputation from 16 to -4. I abandoned Stack Exchange for years after then. A couple of days ago, when I logged back into my account, I found that my reputation had gone back up to 16, and Questions tab said "You have not asked any questions." What happened to my negative reputation?

Comment: Your question was deleted, your rep was 1.  You got [one accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12396593/17034), 1 + 15 = 16.

Answer (score 13):

> reducing my reputation from 16 to -4

No way that happened. The minimum reputation is 1. You can't go under that.

Regardless - what happened is that the question got deleted. And the reputation changes it caused - gone with it.

Comment: If questions get deleted, isn't there the chance of people re-asking the same question? If the original question isn't deleted, people are more likely to realize that they are writing a duplicate.

Comment: @moaz786 - isn't it best to have bad questions gone? Even if they get re-asked? If the bad stuff is not there, only the good stuff remains.

Comment: Downvoted questions without answers get auto-deleted after a while. That's likely what happened.

Comment: @Pekka웃 - looks like that's the case